# jquery autoComplete combobox doesn't apply on new elements loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, combobox, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autoComplete plugin on a combobox (select), The problem is that this combobox is loaded via ajax , Therefore , autocomplete plugin is not applied on this combobox i'm loading , I know that i must use .on() so as javascript can be applied on new elements too but i didn't figure out how to 
this is autoComplete code :

```
      $(function() {
    $( ".combobox" ).combobox();
    $(document).on('click', '.toggle', function() {
      $( ".combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to reinitialize the autocomplete for ajax loaded content.  You can skip for elements those already have,  otherwise bind autocomplete. 
Call below function with the selector you want to apply the combobox. Whenever you update content via ajax, just call this method.

```
function initCombobox(selector) {
    var combos = $(selector);
    $.each(combos, function (i, e) {
        if (!$(e).data('combobox')) {
            $(e).combobox();
        }
    });
}
```

call like : `initCombobox(".combobox");`

Comment: When it comes to jQuery and Javascript i'm a beginner so i'd apreciate if you could give me a hint using a code .

Comment: Thanks for you effort, But there's still the same problem , It's not applied on the select loaded via ajax ...

Comment: I used your method, And i called it again in ajax success, And it worked , Thank you very much i really apreciate it